# Me genera error al intentar insertar datos en la bd

Tags: php, mysqli

Me genera error al intentar insertar en mi base de datos, envío los datos desde un formulario `PHP` y cuando intento que inserte la información dice:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\asec\admin\insertar.php:91 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\asec\admin\insertar.php on line 91" .

¿Qué ocurre?

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$idemp = $_POST['idemp'];
$idsol = $_POST['idsol'];
$idusu = $_POST['idusu'];
$idres= $_POST['idres'];
$idfor = $_POST['idfor'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cargo_aspira = $_POST['cargo_aspira'];
$observacion_relacion = $_POST['observacion_relacion'];
$Por = $_POST['Por'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO relaciones (id, idemp, idsol, idusu, idres, idfor, cargo_aspira, observacion_relacion, estado_relacion, Por) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$id, $idemp, $idsol, $idusu, $idres, $idfor, $cargo_aspira, $observacion_relacion, $estado, $Por]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de consultas (preparadas) pueden retornar el estado del objeto o FALSE al ejecutar la sentencia, si tu tienes un False quiere decir que hay un error al ejecutar la consulta. El mensaje que tienes es recurrente cuando existe algún error de sintaxis, algún carácter especial que no acepte la columna o columnas con nombre diferente al de la sentencia, entre otros.

trata de imprimir el error utilizando lo siguiente, debería ser algo por el estilo, pero la solución va de la mano con atrapar el error:

```
if($stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql) )
{
    $stmt->execute([$id, $idemp, $idsol, $idusu, $idres, $idfor, $cargo_aspira, $observacion_relacion, $estado, $Por]);

}
else
{
        printf('error_nro: %d, error: %s', $conexion->errno, $conexion->error);
        die();
}
```